# Android ListView cell image cut off

Tags: android, listview

No matter what I try, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc, my last image does not display.  id/arrowImage does not show up.  This should be pretty simple, been fighting with it for an hour.

```
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:id="@+id/list_cell"   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
android:layout_height="150px"
android:background="@drawable/round">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_width="140px"
    android:layout_height="140px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"     
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"                    
    />                                  
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
    android:src="@drawable/mainArrow"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"          
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:padding="3px"       
     /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your id/mainText is pushing the image outside the visible area.
Try to put a short text or nothing at all and make sure drawable/mainArrow isn't too big.

Once it come visible you can start to fix it as you like, can't provide a precise solution because you didn't tell what where you trying to achieve.

Comment: you're right, but why is it pushing it out of the view?  doesnt make sense that it would push it outside.  i need the imageview to take up as much space as it needs and then for the textview to size the rest

Answer (score 0):

Okay this works, I ditched the relativelayout...

TableView inside LinearLayout inside a parent LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/round"
android:id="@+id/list_row_lin_layout">
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:id="@+id/list_cell"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
                    android:layout_width="140px"
                    android:layout_height="140px"
                    android:gravity="left"                  
                    />                                  
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mainText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
                    android:paddingRight="2dip"
                    android:textSize="16dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:background="#333333"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/mainArrow"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
                    android:layout_height="32px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="3px" 
                    android:background="#FBEC5D"      
                     /> 
             </TableRow>
         </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay now the click event is not firing AT ALL...great.  :/